# STL algorithms for pairwise comparison and tracking max/longest sequence

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Consider this fairly easy algorithmic problem:

> Given an array of (unsorted) numbers, find the length of the longest sequence of adjacent numbers that are increasing. For example, if we have `{1,4,2,3,5}`, we expect the result to be 3 since {2,3,5} gives the longest increasing sequence of adjacent/contiguous elements. Note that for non-empty arrays, such as {4,3,2,1}, the minimum result will be 1.

This works:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename S>
T max_adjacent_length(const std::vector<S> &nums) {
  if (nums.size() == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  T maxLength = 1;
  T currLength = 1;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < nums.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (nums[i + 1] > nums[i]) {
      currLength++;
    } else {
      currLength = 1;
    }
    maxLength = std::max(maxLength, currLength);
  }
  return maxLength;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<double> nums = {1.2, 4.5, 3.1, 2.7, 5.3};
  std::vector<int> ints = {4, 3, 2, 1};
  std::cout << max_adjacent_length<int, double>(nums) << "\n"; // 2
  std::cout << max_adjacent_length<int, int>(ints) << "\n"; // 1
  return 0;
}
```

As an exercise for myself, I was wondering if there is/are STL algorithm(s) that achieve the same effect, thereby (ideally) avoiding the raw for-loop I have. The motivation behind doing this is to learn more about STL algorithms, and practice using abstracted algorithms to make my code more general and reusable.

Here are my ideas, but they don't *quite* achieve what I'd like.

- `std::adjacent_find` achieves the pairwise comparisons and can be used to find the index of a non-increasing pair, but doesn't easily facilitate the ability to keep a current and maximum length and compare the two. It could be possible to have those state variables as part of my predicate function, but that seems a bit wrong since ideally you'd like your predicate function to not have any side effects, right?
- `std::adjacent_difference` is interesting. One could use it to construct a vector of the differences between adjacent numbers. Then, starting from the second element, depending on if the difference is positive or negative, we could again track the maximum number of consecutive positive differences seen. This is actually quite close to achieving what we'd like. See the example code below:

  ```
  #include <numeric>
  #include <vector>

  template <typename T, typename S> T max_adjacent_length(std::vector<S> &nums) {
    if (nums.size() == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    std::adjacent_difference(nums.begin(), nums.end(), nums.begin());
    nums.erase(std::begin(nums)); // keep only differences
    T maxLength = 1, currLength = 1;
    for (auto n : nums) {
      currLength = n > 0 ? (currLength + 1) : 1;
      maxLength = std::max(maxLength, currLength);
    }
    return maxLength;
  }
  ```

  The problem here is that we lose out the const-ness of `nums` if we want to compute the difference, or we have to sacrifice space and create a copy of `nums`, which is a no-no given the original solution is O(1) space complexity already.

Is there an idea/solution that I have overlooked that achieves what I want in a succinct and readable manner?

Comment: Do you really think that it is necessary to templatize result type? For example `std::vector::size_type` should be sufficient.

Comment: No, I started off with `size_t` before playing around with templating in the case that one may know for a fact that the maximum length might be within an expected range. Either ways, it's not really super relevant to my question so I left it as it was.

Comment: I think more generic and hense more usable would be a function that takes pair of iterators and a comparator functor and return a pair of iterators of longest sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your code snippets, you are iterating through a range (in the first version, with an index-based-loop, and in the second with a range-for loop).  This is not really the kind of code you should be writing if you want to use the standard algorithms, which work with iterators into the range. Instead of thinking of a range as a collection of elements, if you start thinking in terms of pairs of iterators, choosing the right algorithms becomes easier.

For this problem, here's a reasonable way to write this code:

```
auto max_adjacent_length = [](auto const & v)
{
    long max = 0;
    
    auto begin = v.begin();
    
    while (begin != v.end()) {
        auto next = std::is_sorted_until(begin, v.end());
        max = std::max(std::distance(begin, next), max);
        begin = next;              
    }
    
    return max;
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6aEabj).

Note that you were already on the right track in terms of picking a reasonable algorithm. This could be solved with `adjacent_find` as well, with just a little more work.

Comment: "If you think in terms of pairs of iterators, choosing the right algorithms becomes easier..." Just checking if I understand what you mean - the pair you mention here is the begin and end iterators of the vector, as opposed to my loops where I was explicitly iterating over elements?

Comment: Yes, but not just the begin and end of the range. Notice that begin keeps changing, and `distance` uses a different end iterator. It's *any* pair of iterators that represent a sub-range really.